# adding AccountExpirationDate breaks the script

Tags: powershell

I've been using the below to perform some bulk changes for awhile now without a hitch. I recently went to add accountexpirationdate and now it errors. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm setting the value to 0 for "never expires", but it continually errors.

```
import-Csv "d:\temp\script\moduser.csv" | ForEach-Object {
$samAccountName = $_."samAccountName"
$password = $_."password"
$server = $_."server"
Get-ADUser -server $server -Identity $samAccountName | Set-ADUser -PasswordNeverExpires:$True -AccountExpirationDate 0
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $samAccountName -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force)
}
```

Comment: what is the error message? that might be slightly helpful.

Comment: Have you tried ***New-Object Nullable[System.Datetime]*** for the expiration date?

Comment: Invalid argument. Hope that helps.

Comment: What was the actual code that you ran? Did you create a variable and use that? Or enclose the New-Object call in parens?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got my answer....this is what I'm using now and it works:

```
import-Csv "d:\temp\script\moduser.csv" | ForEach-Object {
$samAccountName = $_."samAccountName"
$password = $_."password"
$server = $_."server"
Get-ADUser -server $server -Identity $samAccountName | Set-ADUser -PasswordNeverExpires:$True
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $samAccountName -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force)
set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $samAccountName -DateTime $null
}
```